# App crash on CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll in iOS in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios11, react-native-ios

I am trying to save a screenshot to Camera Roll in my react-native app in iOS but as soon as the CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll is called the app crashes. It was working till iOS 10 and react-native 0.47. And it is working perfectly fine in Android.

I already have the permissions required for iOS 10+ in Info.plist.

This is my code for saving the image to Camera Roll.

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(mUri, 'photo')
.then(()=>console.log('saved to CameraRoll'))
.catch(()=>console.log('error in saving'))
```

Note that I am not getting any of the console logs of above two. It is a native crash and below is the crash thread.

```
Thread 39 Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)
#0  0x000000010c8280aa in __abort_with_payload ()
#1  0x000000010c824326 in abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal ()
#2  0x000000010c82434f in abort_with_payload ()
#3  0x000000010c9d2b09 in __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ ()
#4  0x000000010c9d2a53 in __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.77 ()
#5  0x000000010c9d6273 in __tccd_send_block_invoke ()
#6  0x000000010c76ead5 in _xpc_connection_reply_callout ()
#7  0x000000010c76417c in _xpc_connection_call_reply_async ()
#8  0x000000010c39f49e in _dispatch_client_callout3 ()
#9  0x000000010c3b7658 in _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke ()
#10 0x000000010c3a407d in _dispatch_queue_override_invoke ()
#11 0x000000010c3ab1f9 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#12 0x000000010c3aae97 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#13 0x000000010c85d5a2 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#14 0x000000010c85d07d in start_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.libdispatch-manager (Thread 42) Queue : com.apple.libdispatch-manager (serial)
#0  0x000000010c3b405c in _dispatch_mach_reply_merge_msg ()
#1  0x000000010c3ba3f3 in _dispatch_event_loop_merge ()
#2  0x000000010c3b2481 in _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread ()
#3  0x000000010c85d47b in _pthread_wqthread ()
#4  0x000000010c85d07d in start_wqthread ()
```

Comment: Did you add privacy for `Camera` and `Photo Gallery` in your `info.plist` ? You need to ask for user permission before access the user private data like photos, location, etc. in `iOS 10` Apple is extending the scope of privacy control. You have to declare in `Info.plist` file access of any private data.

Comment: Yes. It is there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I get same problem too. 
Fixed by adding NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription("Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description") in info.plist.

It's a new rule for iOS 11.

Comment: Yeah. Got to same solution after wasting 1 entire day. iOS need to do better logging for issues. :-/

Comment: I needed both permissions from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html